# How both the function act different from each other not in the matter of time complexity

Tags: c++

For the below question where does the both function differ. I have tried stress testing both the function returns the same result. I am trying to submit the **product** function in the competitive programming site it return wrong answer for some test cases, while all the test cases passes for the **max_dot_product** function.

**Task**. Given two sequences 1, 2, . . . ,  (
is the profit per click of the -th ad) and 1, 2, . . . ,  (
is
the average number of clicks per day of the -th slot), we need to partition them into  pairs (
,  )
such that the sum of their products is maximized.

**Input Format**. The first line contains an integer , the second one contains a sequence of integers
1, 2, . . . , , the third one contains a sequence of integers 1, 2, . . . , .

**Constraints**. 1 ≤  ≤ 103
; −105 ≤ 
,  ≤ 105
for all 1 ≤  ≤ .

**Output Format.** Output the maximum value of ∑︀
=1

, where 1, 2, . . . ,  is a permutation of
1, 2, . . . , .

```
int comp(long long a,long long b)
{
return a>b;
}

 long long max_dot_product(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {

      std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    
        vector<long long> c;
        c.reserve(a.size());
    
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c),
                       std::multiplies<long long>());
    
        long long product = std::accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), 0ll);
    
        return product;
    }
      long long product(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
      long long product=0;
      sort(a.begin(),a.end(),comp);
      sort(b.begin(),b.end(),comp);
      for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        product+=a[i]*b[i];
      }
      return product;
    }
```

Comment: In product() the sort statements take a comparator and in max_dot_product() the sort statements use natural ordering.  That could easily make a difference but you don't provide the comparator function.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have updated the question with the comparator function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max_dot_product()` function calculates the products of elements of `a` and `b` by converting them to `long long` and then doing the multiplication.    This happens due to the usage of `std::multiplies<long long>()` which creates a functor with an `operator()` that accepts two `long long` arguments, and returns their product as a `long long`.

In comparison `product+=a[i]*b[i]` calculates the product of `a[i]*b[i]` as an `int` (since both `a[i]` and `b[i]` are of type `int`), and then converts the result of that to `long long` before adding it to `product`.

A consequence of this is that, if the result of computing any of the `a[i]*b[i]` (for any `i`) overflows an `int`, the function `product()` has undefined behaviour.

This can be fixed (at least, in terms of results produced) by changing the statement `product += a[i]*b[i]` to `product += (long long)a[i]*b[i]`.   This explicitly converts `a[i]` to `long long` and, under promotion rules, implicitly also promotes `b[i]` to `long long` BEFORE multiplying them and producing a result of type `long long`, which is then added to `product`.